# Can't install virtualbox guest additions on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install an Ubuntu guest on VirtualBox.  The installation goes ok, but when I try to install Guest Additions I get the following error

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good. 
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.18 Guest Additions for Linux............ 
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ... 
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules. 
vboxadd.sh: You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used. 
vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

You may need to restart the Window System (or just restart the guest system) to enable the Guest Additions.

Press Return to close this window...
```

- Ubuntu 16.04.2
- VirtualBox 5.1.18r114002
- Guest Additions 5.1.18_114002

Any suggestions on how to get guest additions installed?

Comment: This does not look an error message to me.  Did you restart everything?  Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error message.  To get the modules that the Guest Additions adds, you need to restart the VirtualBox VM.  Then the additions should load as part of the kernel.

If you are getting an error message, then it would be stating "ERROR" or such in the message output - not the "You should restart your guest" message.